# Python keyboard input while blocking keyboard for the rest of the system

Tags: python, input, keyboard

**Premise:**

I am trying to have python accept keyboard input and have it lock the keyboard to only python input such as that I can hit a key and "transfer" the keyboard from the entire system to only my python script and have it listen to any keys hit so there's no input terminal or any sort of GUI for input

**Question:**

Is there any way of locking keyboard input to **only** python for a short time? Is there a better way of doing this?

**More Informations:**

I want to have the script "draw", on the screen, when a combination of keys is pressed, for example having ctrl be a square, I can use `keyboard.wait()` to register the hotkey or a combination of them and then just `drawSquare()` using pyautogui or pywin32 or any other means but this would mean that the size of the square, the movement of the mouse would be hardcoded
This I am trying to avoid, I had in mind waiting for a hotkey with keyboard.wait() then just listening for, say, size of square, or coordinates, whatever, and this does work but the problem is keyboard also "types" in whatever program I am as well as python (using `keyboard.record()`) so say I wanted ctrl to begin listening for size and then enter 123 123 for width and height 123 123 would also be entered into whatever program I am in (as it would with natural typing since keyboards are meant to do that)

Comment: Might be possible if you used the `tkinter` module to create the GUI, because it has a `grab_set_global()` widget method that I think will do what you want.

Comment: I've done a little research into this and cobbled up some code but this also, did not work for me, I don't know whether **I did something wrong** or if this simply does not do what I want; `grab_set_global()` made it unable to interact with the tkinter window but with all other windows and apps such that it could not be moved, resized, closed or alike with the mouse, the mouse callback function also printed clicks outside of the tkinter window when it wasn't in focus as well
This is my little snippet
https://ghostbin.co/paste/m9w9oua